# grep - How to return the pattern and the matching line when matching two files?

Tags: regex, grep

I have two files :

pattern.csv which contains data like

```
paul hung
james
julien pierre
```

and clients.csv which contains

```
Paul Hung Chong;3
James Malroy;4
Julien Pierre Take;5
```

I would like to return

```
paul hung;Paul Hung Chong;3
james;James Malroy;4
julien Pierre;Julien Pierre Take;5
```

So that I can create a matching table between the keys defined in the pattern.csv with the ones defined in clients.csv

So far I tried

```
grep -i -F -f 'patterns.csv' 'clients.csv' > matching.csv
```

Which returns

```
Paul Hung Chong;3
James Malroy;4
Julien Pierre Take;5
```

And

```
grep -i -F -f 'patterns.csv' 'clients.csv' > matching.csv
```

which returns

```
Paul Hung
James
Julien Pierre
```

That is to say the patterns or the matched lines. But could I merge both ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -F';' 'FNR==NR{a[++i]=$1;next} {for (k=1; k<=i; k++) 
           if (index(tolower($1), tolower(a[k]))) print a[k], $0}' OFS=';' g1 g2
paul hung;Paul Hung Chong;3
james;James Malroy;4
julien pierre;Julien Pierre Take;5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @anubhava ! It works perfectly. Testing it on the real files I can see that the lines not matching from the clients file are copied. How can I go over this ?

Comment: You mean lines that that are not from file1 in file2 are also needed on output? Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry @anubhava, actually it works perfectly, I got it wrong at first. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

if **gawk** is ok for you:

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 -v OFS=";" 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}
      {for(x in a)if($0~x){print x,$0;break}}' pattern.txt file.csv
```

Note this line has some risk if your pattern file contains regex special meaning chars.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's as simple as finding the right tool for the job

```
$ paste -d';' pattern.csv clients.csv
paul hung;Paul Hung Chong;3
james;James Malroy;4
julien pierre;Julien Pierre Take;5
```

Comment: if the orders of two files are fixed and coresponded

Comment: Thanks ! @FredrikPihl it could have worked indeed if the two files were sorted and with a unique occurence in each. From the examples I provided it is the case but not on the real sample I use

Comment: was worth a try :-) to sort you can do `paste -d';' <(sort f1) <(sort f2)`